# trying to use for loop to generate each month in a table

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

I have created a table in panda/python  to create a table with month as a column and the months/year will be displayed in that column. I've been trying to make it so it shows month after month, so lets say jan and then feb. But the issue I'm facing is that it keeps showing the same month and year throughout the entire column as you can see the month march has been appearing throughout the entire column.

[image]

this is the for loop i've used

```
    month_count = 0 

    for row_num in range (4,20):
    # TABLE 1
    vsr_tracker.write_formula(
    'B' + str(row_num), 
    '=DATE(2016,2+{0},1)'.format(month_count))
              row_num + 1))
```

[as you can see on the screenshot that it the month march has been printed throughout the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI6fz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is not incrementing the months by +1 you have to add to the date in the loop.
If you want to also increase the days by 1 you have to increment the days too.

Comment: try incrementing month_count
do this by adding month_count += 1 before vsr_tracker.write_formula

Comment: If it works please mark the answer as the correct one so we know it is resolved.

Comment: No problem happy to help :)